# Set property path in TS as string and use it dynamically in template to output property value

Tags: angular

```ts
this.gridData = {

firstName: { currentUser: this.loggedUser.firstName, templatePath: 'users.user[0].firstName' },

lastName: { currentUser: this.loggedUser.lastName, templatePath: 'users.user[0].lastName' }

}

this.dataExample = {

users: [user: { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' }]

}
```

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let entry of gridData; let i = index">
   <td class="table-cell">{{ entry.value.templatePath }}</td>
</ng-container>
```

Currently this is outputting as a string and not the property value.

```
users.user[0].firstName
users.user[0].lastName
```

Ideally I want to have output:

```
John
Doe
```

It seems a pipe is the way to go but I am not able to get anything other than a string to output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _"It seems a pipe is the way to go but I am not able to get anything other than a string to output"_ - with what pipe, exactly? Give a [mre]. What you're showing is displaying exactly the string you asked it to.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bit diry but here you go.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let entry of gridData; let i = index">
   <td class="table-cell">{{ getValue(entry.value.templatePath) }}</td>
</ng-container>
```

```
getValue(templatePath: string) {
  return templatePath.split('.').reduce((prev, curr) => prev[curr], this.dataExample);
}
```

This should *drill down* into the object along the path specified by the templatePath string. In the end it should get the value of the property at the end of the path.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to modify the grid data and dataExample little bit in order to make this work

```
loggedUser = {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'}

gridData = {
  firstName: { currentUser: this.loggedUser.firstName, templatePath: 'users[0].user' },
  lastName: { currentUser: this.loggedUser.lastName, templatePath: 'users[0].user' }
}

dataExample = {
   users: [{user: { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' }}]
}
```

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let entry of gridData | keyvalue">
   <td class="table-cell">{{ entry.value.currentUser }}</td>
</ng-container>
```

Do let me know if this help you. Happy Coding and keep smiling :-)